tcolorbox includes temporary filename in box (some time in TeX Live 2023 onwards)
At some point after updates of TeX Live 2023, the temporary filename used when using tcolorbox to make listings was included in the box. I eventually traced this to being caused by a particular sequence of packages. I enclose a MWE. After removing any one of the packages (or even one of the two languages in the document class), the problem does not appear any more. If \input@path is not set the problem also does not appear.
% Directory with style files
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{../}}
\makeatother

\documentclass[ngerman, UKenglish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
% \tcbset{colframe=Blue, colback=Azure}

% \title{tcolorbox test}
% \author{Ian C. Brock}

\begin{document}

% \maketitle

% \section{First section}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
This is some text.
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}

Here is the resultof the compilation using TeX Live 2024: 

the feynmp package activates the " and the following packages don't like that. Either load it before babel or after all the other packages.

Many thanks for the quick fix. Works perfectly!

Just to add an answer based on Ulrike's comment: load feynmp either before babel or after all other packages.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You're right, of course. I'll go through and fix that for other answers of mine

Thank you!!!!!!
